# JAVA After adding a seccond button and its actionListener, actions get executed twice

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, initializer

After adding a listener to a second button, the first created button executes twice the same action:

```
public class ControladorTablaMaterial implements ActionListener {


 private VistaTablaMaterial vistaTablaMaterial;
    private JPanel jContentPane = null;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = null;
    private JTable tablaMaterial;
    private JButton mostrarElementoButton;
    private JButton eliminarElementoButton;
    private ModeloTablaMaterial modeloTablaMaterial;


    public ControladorTablaMaterial(ArrayList<Material> coleccionMaterial, ActionListener listener) {
        String[] cabecera = {"Material", "Titulo"};
        this.vistaTablaMaterial = new VistaTablaMaterial(cabecera, coleccionMaterial);
        setupVistaTablaMAterial(listener);
    }

    private void setupVistaTablaMAterial(ActionListener listener) {
        this.scrollPane = vistaTablaMaterial.getScrollPane();
        this.tablaMaterial = vistaTablaMaterial.getTablaMaterial();
        this.modeloTablaMaterial = vistaTablaMaterial.getModeloTablaMaterial();
        this.mostrarElementoButton = vistaTablaMaterial.getMostrarElementoButton();
        this.eliminarElementoButton = vistaTablaMaterial.getMostrarElementoButton();
        this.initListeners(listener);
    }


    private void initListeners (ActionListener listener) {
        getMostrarElementoButton().addActionListener(listener);
        getEliminarElementoButton().addActionListener(listener);

    }

     @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

}
```

Everything works fine if I delete the line:

```
getEliminarElementoButton().addAtionListener(listener);
```

but of course I need that button to be listened to too.

Inside the listener class, in the actionPerformed(actionEvent e) method, I use the following code to differentiate both buttons:

```
if (e.getSource().equals(this.getControladorTablaMaterial().getMostrarElementoButton())) {
```

That seems to work fine except for this frame. Any guess?

Off topic: why isn't the code indentation working properly on Stackoverflow's editor?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: This is a copy/paste error; voting to close as a problem caused by typo.

Comment: Take a look at the edit you've just undone to see why indentation is not working (long story short, it's because you are not doing it right).

Comment: @daskblinkenlight indentation fixed by selecting all lines but first and clicking on {}. Then selecting the last hanging "}" and clicking againg on {}.

Now I know how it works and can fix it, but I'd call that a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in these lines:

```
this.mostrarElementoButton = vistaTablaMaterial.getMostrarElementoButton();
this.eliminarElementoButton = vistaTablaMaterial.getMostrarElementoButton();
```

That you are getting the same button for both.